# Not showing proper values for structure array in c

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct

I was playing with dynamic allocation and pointers and structures so i got a weird result.
Here is the code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NEW_POINT(x) (POINT *)malloc(x*sizeof(POINT))
#define EXTEND(ptr,size) (POINT *)realloc(ptr,size*sizeof(POINT))

typedef struct p{
  int x;
  int y;
}POINT;
POINT *g;

void show(POINT *s){
  printf("x = %d\ty = %d\n",s->x,s->y );

}
POINT* getPoint() {
  POINT *t = NEW_POINT(1);
  t->x = rand()%50;
  t->y = rand()%50;
  return t;
  //memcpy(g,t,sizeof(*t));
}

int main() {
  POINT *temp;
  srand(time(NULL));
  g = getPoint();
  show(g);
  g  = EXTEND(g,2);
  show(g);
  temp = g;
  temp++;
  temp = getPoint();

  //free(temp);
  show(g);
  show(++g);

return 0 ;
}
```

I'm here creating two element array, in a bit tricky proccess. I'm expecting that the last to lines should show the g[0] and g[1 ] of the array.
But the output is like this.[image: Output of the program]

Please help..

Comment: `temp = getPoint` just puts a new pointer into `temp`. It has no effect on the memory that `g` points to.

Comment: ok i understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is because your code is not copying the data into the extra space you assigned for a POINT *. I modified the code in main(), to copy the data into that space, the following should work.

```
int main() {
  POINT *temp;
  srand(time(NULL));
  g = getPoint();
  show(g);
  g  = EXTEND(g,2);
  show(g);
  temp = getPoint();

  /* This line copies the data from the new point referred to by temp
     into the extra space you allocated for g[1].*/
  memcpy(g+1, temp, sizeof(POINT));

  //free(temp);
  show(g);
  show(++g);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13uSUhl4Y4NTX5f61upRLkUVljZXzFN6w/view?usp=sharing) case? Why there is a seg fault?

Comment: The main reason is because no memory is allocated to g when your code calls show(g).

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong...in 2nd example I'm sending an pointer with call by value hence the actual parameters are unaltered...so if I use **p then altering the formal Parameters would change the actual ones.. i.e. call by reference.. right?

Comment: Ok, yes in the 2nd example you pass in a pointer, which is a value. However it is also a reference to an address. So while you can modify the data at the address that it points to, assigning a value to the argument after it has been passed in does not change it because it's just a copy of the value of the address you passed in. Also *p can be used to change the value at the address pointed to by pointer p, like *p = 100 (for example if p is a pointer to an integer `int *p`).

Comment: Hey also please can you accept the answer if it works for you :)